# How to use wait function inside Nightmare action evaluate_now?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I'm using Nightmare actions inside my script. Inside the action I'm using evaluate_now function, how can I use wait function in it?
I know that I can use wait function inside action by calling `this.wait('example')` 
But wait function is not accessable inside the `this.evaluate_now` function.

```
Nightmare.action('example', function(done){
    this.evaluate_now(function() {
       //do some calculation and get element id
       var element = 'calculatedelement';
       activeTask.querySelector(element ).click();
       //I have to use the wait function here
    }        
    this.wait('body'); //wait is accessible here 
});
```

Comment: See https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/402#issuecomment-166948532

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use an action inside an evaluate_now(), and wait() is an action in the library ([Source](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/blob/2d3cfaca1fdfc07a9bfb9a7db4de0d85fe4300c3/lib/actions.js#L411)). The code which is provided in evaluate_now() is executed in the electron instance ([Source](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/blob/2d3cfaca1fdfc07a9bfb9a7db4de0d85fe4300c3/lib/nightmare.js#L379)).

Instead of that, you can create a waiting by using setTimeout() function in callback function of evaluate_now(). The next example is an action which checks if an element is visible in the viewport or not.

```
Nightmare.action('waitInViewport', function (selector, done) {
    // Keep evaluation function in a variable
    const evalFn = () => {
        this.evaluate_now((selector) => {
            const element = document.querySelector(selector);

            if (!element) {
                return false;
            }

            const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();

            const height = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
            const width = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);

            return !(rect.top >= height || rect.bottom <= 0 ||
                rect.left >= width || rect.right <= 0);
        }, (err, isVisible) => {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            if (isVisible) {
                return done(null, isVisible);
            }

            // If we are here, so we didn't found the element, so just run another evaluation after a delay
            setTimeout(evalFn, 500);
        }, selector);
    };

    // Don't forget to do the first call of the evaluation
    evalFn();
});
```

Another way is just to call the wait() function before you call your custom action.

```
Nightmare
    .wait('#myComponent')
    .example();
```

Remember that custom actions with evaluate_now() are limited to do some synchronous instructions, and maybe aren't adapted to your use-case.